# Android hybrid app gives me "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier", source: (1)

Tags: javascript, android, json, webview

I received a **valid JSON** from the server, but Chromium tells me this error:

> "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier", source: (1)

All I know is that when I call the following method:

```
stringBuilder.append("javascript: javascriptBridge.getHandlers().showPost('");
stringBuilder.append(e.getData());
stringBuilder.append("');");
webView.loadUrl(stringBuilder.toString());
```

Where `e.getData()` is the valid JSON, it doesn't actually get called on the other side. Something in the JSON is interpreted incorrectly as a javascript function parameter

```
javascriptBridge.registerHandler('showPost', function (data) {
     alert('showpost'); //this is not called
});
```

It works for other datas and it worked previously even for JSON, that is why it's odd. Any ideas how to fix it? It's probably some character that crashes it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following fixed it, thanks to `commons-lang3`:

```
 StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
 stringBuilder.append("javascript: javascriptBridge.getHandlers().showPost('");
 stringBuilder.append(StringEscapeUtils.escapeEcmaScript(e.getData()));
 stringBuilder.append("');");
 webView.loadUrl(stringBuilder.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

`StringEscapeUtils.escapeEcmaScript` solves the problem, add this library to your gradle:

```
compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'
```